# Take a screenshot of a particular area

Tags: delphi, screenshot, lazarus, fpc

I am using Lazarus and I have a TImage inside a form. The black table is a `TImage` and the numbers are `labels`. I need to take a screenshot of the red area I drew.

[image]

How can I perform this?

I have Lazarus 1.0.14 and I didn't find any example about this. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why did you use TImage and TLabel. Much better to paint direct to a canvas.

Comment: Much easier, though, to draw the grid once in Paint, and then never have to paint anything else in the program, @David. I'd much prefer to assign labels' Caption properties and let Delphi draw the text than to write the layout and text-drawing code myself. Were this my project, I'd probably forego the grid image and just assign the labels' background colors to create the same grid effect. Or use a real grid control.

Comment: Alberto, did you really not find any examples of making screen shots? I can understand not seeing any examples of getting specific areas of the screen, but once you get the image of the entire screen, you can use ordinary image-editing functions to extract a specific area of the image, regardless of the original source of the image.

Comment: @Rob, Lazarus is more benevolent in publishing canvas, so if you just put all the controls on a borderless panel, you can really just copy its canvas content. It's not that easy in Delphi.

Comment: I didn't use canvas because, as @RobKennedy said, I preferred make that with Paint. It's faster.

Comment: Wait until you need to change the layout, or have font scaling? What if a user prefers larger fonts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a painful design, but well, one simple way might be to put all the controls on a common container and copy its canvas to a bitmap. The following example assumes, that you have put your image and all the labels on a common `TPanel` control (`Panel1`):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRect;
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    R := Rect(0, 0, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height);
    Bitmap.SetSize(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height);
    Bitmap.Canvas.CopyRect(R, Panel1.Canvas, R);
    Bitmap.SaveToFile('C:\Screenshot.bmp');
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `GetFormImage` to get the form image, and keep the part that corresponds to your image area in it:

```
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  Bmp := GetFormImage;
  try
    Bmp.Canvas.CopyRect(Image1.ClientRect, Bmp.Canvas, Image1.BoundsRect);
    Bmp.SetSize(Image1.Width, Image1.Height);
    Bmp.SaveToFile('....');
  finally
    Bmp.Free;
  end;
```